# C forward declaration of struct in header

Tags: c, struct, forward-declaration

I am trying to pass `struct` pointer in function. I have a `typedef` in file1.h, and want to only include that header to file2.c, because file2.h only need pointer. In C++ I would just write like I did here, but using C99 it doesn't work. If someone has any suggestions how to pass `struct` pointer without full definition it would be very appreciated. Compiler - gcc.

file1.h

```
typedef struct
{
    ...
} NEW_STRUCT;
```

file2.h

```
struct NEW_STRUCT;

void foo(NEW_STRUCT *new_struct); //error: unknown type name 'NEW_STRUCT'
```

file2.c

```
#include "file2.h"

#include "file1.h"

void foo(NEW_STRUCT *new_struct)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: *"it doesn't work."*  Explain that.  Did you get a compiler error? a a linker error? a run time crash?  What happened?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that. It doesn't compile neither like that, neither if i add `struct` to function argument, then the error changes to "function 'foo' argument type missmatch".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you just have to name your structure, and do a forward declaration of it and after re typedef it.

First file:

```
 typedef struct structName {} t_structName;
```

Second file:

```
  struct stuctName;
  typedef struct structName t_structName
```

Comment: Was hoping for a solution not involving re typedef'ing, but I'll have to accept this.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

file1.h

```
typedef struct _NEW_STRUCT  // changed!
{
    ...
} NEW_STRUCT;
```

file2.h

```
struct _NEW_STRUCT; // changed!

void foo(struct _NEW_STRUCT *new_struct); // changed!
```

file2.c

```
#include "file2.h"
#include "file1.h"

void foo(NEW_STRUCT *new_struct)
{
    ...
}
```