# error c2371 struct <type> redefinition

Tags: c, syntax-error, visual-studio-debugging

So, I get the error above multiple times in Visual studio. Here's my code:
**Union.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#ifndef AI_H
#define AI_H
#include "AI.h"
#endif

#ifndef UI_H
#define UI_H
#include "UI.h"
#endif

typedef struct BOARD_CELL {
    int player, wall, steps;
}CELL;

typedef struct {
    int x, y;
}COORD;
```

**AI.h**

```
#include "union.h"
void pathfind(CELL **a, int n);
void ai(CELL **a);
void genmove(CELL **a);
```

**UI.h**

```
#include "union.h"

void cmdtoAct(char* c, CELL **a, char player_counter, COORD white_vertex, COORD black_vertex);
void placeWall( CELL **a, char* str, char* str2, int n);
void playmove( CELL **a, char *colour, char *vertex, COORD player_vertex);
int pathCheck( CELL **a);
void showBoard( CELL **a);
void backdoor();
char* getCmd();
```

All you need to know about the .c files is that each and every one of them has to know about the existance of the CELL struct and of the COORDS struct and that since they are typedefed, when i use them in  my functions as parameters, i call them as "CELL **variable" for example, and not as "struct CELL **variable".

EDIT: I added guards to both the ai.h and ui.h like this:
**AI.h**

```
#ifndef AI_H
#define AI_H
#include "union.h"
#endif

void pathfind(CELL **a, int n);
void ai(CELL **a);
void genmove(CELL **a);
```

**UI.h**

```
#ifndef UI_H
#define UI_H
#include "union.h"
#endif

void cmdtoAct(char* c, CELL **a, char player_counter, PLAYER white, PLAYER    black);
void placeWall( CELL **a, char* str, char* str2, int n);
void playmove( CELL **a, char *colour, char *vertex, PLAYER player);
int pathCheck( CELL **a);
CELL **boardsize(struct CELL **a, int size);
void showBoard( CELL **a);
void backdoor();
char* getCmd();
```

And now I get a C2143 SYNTAX ERROR MISSING '{' before ' * '
And a C2143 SYNTAX ERROR missing ')' before ' * '

What is going on???!!!

Comment: The [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) must be placed in the included header, that is in Union.h, in UI.h and AI.h. As is, Union.h is included twice ! Once by AI.h and once by UI.h.

Comment: AI.h includes Union.h which includes AI.h? Chicken or egg?

Comment: The answer of @Joyas to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913871/c-forward-declaration-of-struct-in-header regarding forward declaration of struct in c might help you.

Comment: @francis , look at the edit please! I am losing my mind!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Header files should start with [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). For instance, `union.h` would look like :

```
#ifndef UNION_H  //include guard
#define UNION_H  //include guard
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "AI.h"
#include "UI.h"

typedef struct BOARD_CELL {
   int player, wall, steps;
}CELL;

typedef struct {
   int x, y;
}COORD;
#endif  //include guard
```

That way, the egg-chiken problem of circular inclusion is prevented: `union.h` includes `AI.h`. Then `AI.h` includes `union.h` but the include guard `UNION_H` is now defined and nothing is included from `union.h`. Hence, recursive inclusion stops here. It should be mentioned that the whole header file `union.h` should be enclosed by the `#ifndef UNION_H ... #endif`.

A new issue arises : if `union.h` is included first, `AI.h` is included before the definition of the structure `CELL`. But functions in `AI.h` operate on `CELL**` ! To solve this problem, let's introduce ***a forward declaration*** of `CELL` in `AI.h`(see [C forward declaration of struct in header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913871/c-forward-declaration-of-struct-in-header) ):

```
#ifndef AI_H
#define AI_H
#include "union.h"

//forward declaration of struct CELL
struct BOARD_CELL;
typedef struct BOARD_CELL CELL;

void pathfind(CELL **a, int n);
void ai(CELL **a);
void genmove(CELL **a);

#endif
```

Again, thanks to the include guard, the content of `AI.h` will not be included twice.

I did not check the code above. Let me know if your problem is not solved !